# OSX Terminal |& doesn't work

Tags: macos

I've noticed that

```
$ make |& less
```

doesn't work in the OSX Terminal but it does on any linux machine. I am referring of course to the `|&` part of the command in bash. Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash before version 4, use `make 2>&1 | less`.

Comment: ah! thanks! Yes I only use bash.

Comment: `!&` was introduced in Bash 4.  As of 10.9, OS X still ships versions of Bash 3.

Comment: (That should be `|&` of course.)